# Bulk copy from Cassandra table column to a file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a requirement to copy cassandra database column into a file.
The databas has 15 million records with below columns in it. I want to copy payment column data into a file.  Since it a production environment that will leads to stress on cassandra clusters.

```
userid      | contract | payment | createdDate
```

Any suggestions?

Out of 15 millions payment details we want to modify few (based on some condition) and insert into a different Cassandra table.

Copying to a file -> process it -> write it to new Database table. that is the plan. but first of all how to get the copy of the column from cassandra database.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spark + [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) (SCC) to perform data loading, modification and writing back. SCC has a number of knobs that you can use to tune throughput, to not overload the cluster when reading & writing.

If you don't have Spark, you can still use the similar approach when fetching data - not issuing the `select * from table` (this will overload the node that handles request), but instead perform loading of the data by specific token ranges, so the queries will go to different servers and don't overload them too much. You can find code example that is doing scan by token ranges [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java).

Comment: as per the git code you suggested, it only gets the data from one node ?  how about the data in different nodes in the cluster?  Also if the program fails for some reason in halfway how do we resume from there when we start again? please help

Comment: No. It gets data from all nodes in cluster, depending what part of data is owned by that node

Comment: I did not try this yet.. but it is more relevant approach.  We are in design phase and possibilities of looking for approaches and this is seems to be opt for us.  Accepting this solution.